# django importing ldap libraries

Tags: python, django, ldap, backend

I am starting working with Django and also this is my first post here so I want to apologize for any mistakes.

I have installed Django 1.9 and ldap libraries.

Importing ldap works fine but when I want to import ldap auth

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = ""
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = ""
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=users,dc=example,dc=com",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")
```

i get the error:

> ImportError: No module named django_auth_ldap.config

Does it mean that I should import something else?

Comment: Why do you have 2 imports on the same statement?

Comment: @AmalSurendran That was a side-effect of user using blockquote instead of code-formatting.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pip install django-auth-ldap
```

Install this package.

Comment: I can't use pip install because linux is working offline and I don't have any connection to internet

Comment: django-auth-ldap is missing and that is why you are getting this error

Comment: Can I download it in a package and trasnfer to this machine?

Comment: ofcourse you can. Transfer the package and install from the source